# Find a specific paragraph

Tags: vba, ms-word

As the picture shows, I want to find this paragraph of the red, but not find the paragraph marked as green.
  I tried the following code. However, no response to run, someone can tell me how to improve this code. If i make any low-level mistakes, hope can correct me,  thank you.

```
Sub qw()
Dim p As Paragraph, d As Document
For Each p In ActiveDocument.Range.Paragraphs
If p.Format.FirstLineIndent = CentimetersToPoints(0) And p.Range.Words(1) = "Author" Then
p.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdRed
End If
Next

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
If p.Format.FirstLineIndent = CentimetersToPoints(0) And p.Range.Words(1) = "Author " Then
    p.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdRed
End If
```

You need to add the space after `Author`, as far as it is part of the word as well. Learn to debug with <kbd>F8</kbd>, it will be of great use for you in simple tasks like this one.

**Edit:**
As suggested in the comment, `InStr(p.Range.Words(1), "Author")` will eliminate the need for adding a space to the searched.

Comment: I would suggest instr(p.Range.Words(1), "Author"). It will work even if Author is followed by hard space or something like that.

Comment: @MarcinSzaleniec - sounds probably better. I was thinking to use `Left()`, but I found out that it does not exist in VBA for Word.

Comment: @MarcinSzaleniec Thank you for your suggestion！！I will try more.